# Raspberry Pi 4 running OpenOCD can't flash ATSAMC21G18A that drives SWD pins

Tags: raspberry-pi, reset, swd, openocd, atsamc21

I'm attempting to flash a Duet 3 ToolBoard 1LC that drives some lights on the board using the SWD pins from a Raspberry Pi running OpenOCD 0.11.0. I'm using the following configuration:

```
adapter driver bcm2835gpio
bcm2835gpio_peripheral_base 0xFE000000
bcm2835gpio_speed_coeffs 236181 60
bcm2835gpio_swd_nums 25 24
bcm2835gpio_srst_num 18

transport select swd

set CHIPNAME at91samc21g18
source [find target/at91samdXX.cfg]

reset_config srst_only srst_nogate connect_assert_srst

adapter srst delay 100
adapter srst pulse_width 100

adapter speed 200

init
targets
reset halt
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, resulting in the following error:

```
# sudo openocd    
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
       http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : BCM2835 GPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : clock speed 200 kHz
Error: Error connecting DP: cannot read IDR

Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
^Cshutdown command invoked
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this board to fail to connect from OpenOCD? Supposedly an Atmel ICE can connect to this board without issue.